# Handling cocoa errors from (NS)URLSession in Swift 3

Tags: cocoa, error-handling, swift3, nsurlsession

### How to handle errors from cocoa frameworks in Swift 3 now that `NSError` is gone?

Swift 3 improved NSError Bridging - https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md

What I do not understand from that document is how to use the improved error bridging.

Let's say, I have the following code, written in Swift 2.3, where I'm trying to find out what the actual error is:

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in

   guard let error = error { else return }
   if error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
       print("cancelled.")
   } else {
       print("error occured: \(error)")
   }
}
```

The corresponding Swift 3 method provides plain `Error` in its completion handler according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask):

```
func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

How do I migrate the mentioned code to Swift 3? I guess casting to NSError is not the correct answer.

Comment: " I guess casting to `NSError` is not the correct answer" ... Actually, I think that is the correct answer if you want `code` and `domain`. As the documentation goes on to say, it "provides any resulting `NSData`, `URLResponse`, and `NSError` objects inside the completion handler."

Answer (score 1):

`Error` is a protocol which includes also a potential `NSError`.

*I guess casting to NSError* **is** the right answer.

Practically just optional bind to `NSError`

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

   guard let nserror = error as? NSError else { return }
   if nserror.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && nserror.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
       print("cancelled.")
   } else {
       print("error occured: \(nserror)")
   }
}
```

If you have more different errors use a `switch` statement and pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @vadian. I still believe there's must be a better, solution than casting to NSError object with weakly typed userInfo as this is exactly what the proposal #112 describes as ugly and hard: "... makes it extremely hard to access common information, such as the localized description. Moreover, the userInfo dictionary is effectively untyped ... "

Comment: In this particular case `URLSession` does return (NS)Errors related to the `NSURLErrorDomain`. As mentioned in the answer an alternative is `switch` and pattern matching.